# How to write Rails 3 scoped in Rails 4 format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class, Event, that has a field starts_at to say when the event starts, in datetime. The start of the Rails 3 version of this class looked as follows:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :between, lambda {|start_time, end_time|
    {:conditions => ["? < starts_at < ?", Event.format_date(start_time), Event.format_date(end_time)] }
  }
```

In the Event controller, the use of this to index events within a timeframe is as follows:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /events
  # GET /events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.scoped
    @events = Event.between(params['start'], params['end']) if (params['start'] && params['end'])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @events }
    end
  end
```

How do I rewrite the lamda for Rails 4, especially the ":condition =>" to scope it between the start and end times as shown in the (pretty straightforward) original lamda? I understand the original, but I cannot think how to use "where(...)" to get a time between two limit, as previously done with the condition.

Also, what do I use in the controller now that Event.scoped is deprecated?

Many thanks.

Comment: that was old-style syntax even in Rails 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# in model
scope :between, ->(from, to) { 
  where(starts_at: (Event.format_date(from)..Event.format_date(to)))
}

# in controller
@events = Event.all
if params['start'] && params['end']
  @events = @events.between(params['start'], params['end'])  
end
...
```

Please note the `BETWEEN` syntax in Mysql has a slightly different meaning than your original query. Your query was `<`, `BETWEEN` uses `<=`.

Comment: Should also work in Postgres, see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-comparison.html

Comment: This works, but can I ask if the first line in the controller shouldn't be "@events = Event.all" as "scoped" is now deprecated according to the api? The idea (apparently) is that Event.all returns an activerelation object as opposed to actually fetching a huge array. This is what I think I am reading about in the guides, but not sure?

Comment: @tentimes: You are right, the first line in the controller should end with `.all`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Using where**

Actually changing :conditions to where is pretty straightforward. What you need in most cases is just change :conditions to where method as following:

```
{:conditions => ["name = ?", custom_name]}

where(name: custom_name)
```

In other cases you need to chain the where method with others already provided by rails:

```
{:conditions => ["name = ?", custom_name], :limit => 10}

where(name: custom_name).limit(10)
```

About comparing dates, rails knows how to handle it using ranges... for example:

```
where(create_at: 2.days.ago..Time.now)
```

or yourself can set a specific command to database.

**About Model#scoped**

Now it's useless, because rails use lazy loading and methods like where, all, order, etc.. are chainable. So you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
scope :between, lambda { |start_time, end_time|
  where('? < starts_at AND starts_at < ?', Event.format_date(start_time), Event.format_date(end_time))
}
```

And BTW, this syntax is valid (and recommended) in Rails 3 also.

Now, `Event.all` is equivalent to deprecated `Event.scoped` - i.e. it returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` (and not an `Array`, like it used to).

Comment: Actually he is asking for `RAils 4 scope(lambda)` i guess.

Comment: @Pavan explain what you mean please.

Comment: "How do I rewrite the lamda for Rails 4, especially the ":condition =>" to scope it between the start and end times as shown in the (pretty straightforward) original lamda?" from thse lines of OP's post i guess so.

Comment: @Pavan I still don't understand. There's no other syntax in Rails 4 than AREL syntax in scopes. Plus, is it your downvote?

Comment: @Pavan notice also sentence "I understand the original, but I cannot think how to use "where(...)" to get a time between two limit, as previously done with the condition." in question.

Comment: Yes! He is referring that line too with how to write it in Rails 4,not in Rails 3.

Comment: @Pavan ok, if you feel it's wrong, feel free to edit my answer (or to add your own), because I still don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Well spickerman's answer will make you understand. And I'm not yet familiar with rails 4 to write my answer.

Comment: This is much i can give you to help http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments

Comment: : SELECT "meetings".* FROM "meetings"  WHERE ('2014-04-27 00:00:00' < starts_at < '2014-06-08 00:00:00')
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

PG::SyntaxError - ERROR:  syntax error at or near "<"
LINE 1: ...etings"  WHERE ('2014-04-27 00:00:00' < starts_at < '2014-06...                      ^

Comment: @spickermann thanks for edit - I didn't notice that also SQL syntax was wrong here.